# Move Object to OU based on Month

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi First time Posting here and new to PS, In Our AD we have an OU Called Disabled and 12 child OU's named by month i currently have a script to disable the user remove o365 license, convert to a shared mailbox and move to disabled OU. what i would like to do is move the disabled user to the OU of the month the action of disabling takes place.

```
#edit here
$NewHire = "Some.Guy"
$mobph = "123-555-1212"
$stree = "155 any ST"
$cit = "Orlando"
$sta = "Florida"
$zip = "55555"
#end Edit
$user = Get-ADUser $NewHire -Properties 

mail,ProxyAddresses,Office,Company,Country,OfficePhone,streetaddress,city,state,PostalCode,MobilePhone
$user.ProxyAddresses = "SMTP:$NewHire@somedomain.com"
$user.mail = "$NewHire@somedomain.com"
$user.Office = "Remote"
$user.Company = "Company name"
$user.Country = "US"
$user.streetaddress = "$stree"
$user.city = "$cit"
$user.state = "$sta"
$user.PostalCode = "$zip"
$user.MobilePhone = "$mobph"
Set-ADUser -instance $user
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 
https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic - 
AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Connect-MsolService
Get-Date -Format G
Start-Sleep -s 270
Disable-ADAccount -Identity "$NewHire"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership "$NewHire" | Select Name | Export-CSV -path C:\MemberOf\$NewHire.csv - 
NoTypeInformation
Get-ADUser "$NewHire" -Properties MailNickName | Set-ADUser -Replace @{MailNickName = "$NewHire"}
Get-ADUser -Identity "$NewHire" -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
$_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
}
Get-ADUser "$newhire" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=North 
America,DC=123,DC=local"
Set-ADUser $NewHire -Replace @{msExchHideFromAddressLists=$true}

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "$NewHire@somedomain.com" -RemoveLicenses "somecorp:SPE_E3"
```

Comment: What did you try to solve your issue?

Comment: What is the naming convention of the monthly OUs?

Comment: @AdminOfThings  01 - January Through 12 - December

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it seems that you just need to change the OU that the users are being moved to a child OU labeled as the month.

You can get the current month doing something like the following.    You can change the "yyyy-MM" part to the format you would like.

```
$month = [datetime]::Today.ToString("yyyy-MM")
```

Then change the line

```
Get-ADUser "$newhire" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=North America,DC=123,DC=local"
```

to

```
Get-ADUser "$newhire" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$month,OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=North 
America,DC=123,DC=local"
```

Make sure that you create the OU first before asking the script to move users to it.

Comment: can you explain "make sure you Create the OU First" i already have OU's named January through December in Disabled Accounts

Comment: Sure.  I assumed you would be creating folders with month and year to avoid reusing the same folders every year.  In the line above I $month would be 2021--02 so you would need an existing OU called "2021-02"  If you really want just month you can use `$month = [datetime]::Today.ToString("MMMM")`